# Frostpunk: How do you get perfect 60 degree spokes

Tags: frostpunk

I see pictures around of people's city layouts and they always seem to have nice, perfect 60 degree spoke roads. Is there some trick to laying those out crisply? I can't eyeball sixty degrees and the buildings don't seem to hit those marks for me.

Answer (score 1):

Build tents/medical posts around the first layer of the generator. Then starting at an inner corner of the stockpile, build roads out every 2nd tent/medpost.

Hope it helped, might be a bit late lol :)